# Getting error while adding firebase analytics in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

Got this error after adding firebase_analytics in pubsec.yaml file.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':firebase_core:compileDebugAidl'.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0]], but resolves to 16.0.3. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

these are dependencies in pubsec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  firebase_analytics:
  cloud_firestore:
  graphql_flutter: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth:
  firebase_core:
  mobx: ^0.1.2
  flutter_mobx: ^0.1.1
  mobx_codegen: ^0.1.0+1
  carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

thanks

Comment: Are you also using another Firebase plugin?

Comment: I am using this             apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Ok, that's fine. But another FlutterFire plugin? Like FirebaseAuth or Firestore?

Comment: i have update my query @GabrielMoreyra

Comment: My first advice, use specific versions of those plugins. Try using the last one of each. Or look for the versions on your External Libraries -> Flutter Plugins directory and put them on your pubspec.yaml. That way we'll know what you're using exactly. (This will keep you safe from breaking changes on those plugins in the future also)

Comment: Ok that resolves my current problem.but got a new one after updating to latest version of firebase.Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate the behavior you've reported at present. Per checking the comments, it looks like that the issue has been solved. Running `flutter clean` should also solve most conflicts caused in the dependencies cache.